# Confidence interval for correlation

Tags: self-study, correlation, confidence-interval, fisher-transform

I know the confidence interval of an estimated correlation can be calculated after performing Fisher transformation.

But I never figured out why. I also couldn't find the explanation online. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Sorry, but I find your question not very clearly expressed. What exactly do you want explained?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nick Cox has a really good explanation in a 2008 [Speaking Stata column](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0041#Page=4) from SJ that I will excerpt here:

> pwcorr [DVM: Stata's pairwise correlation command] offers only a $p$-value from the
>   standard $t$ test of whether the population correlation $\rho$ is really
>   zero. .... The latter $t$ test cannot be converted into useful
>   confidence intervals, because once the population correlation is
>   really not zero, the sampling distribution of estimates $r$ is
>   substantially skewed, even for large sample sizes. That should not
>   seem surprising, given that correlations are constrained to fall
>   within $[−1, 1]$. Getting at the form of the distribution is a messy
>   problem with, for the most part, only complicated exact solutions, but
>   for practical data analysts an attractive way forward is offered by a
>   suggestion of Ronald Aylmer Fisher (1890–1962): even though $r$ usually
>   has an awkward skewed distribution, the inverse hyperbolic tangent, or
>   atanh, of $r$ is much better behaved. This transform, within statistics
>   often labeled Fisher’s $z$, is said to be normally distributed to a good
>   approximation. The basic tactic is now evident: apply standard
>   normal-based technique on the $z$ scale, and then back-transform using
>   its inverse transform, the hyperbolic tangent, or tanh.

Bootstrapping is a more modern alternative to the classical transformation approach.