# How to estimate confidence interval for weighted correlation

Tags: correlation, uncertainty, weights

It is my understanding that the confidence interval for a Pearson correlation is asymmetric. ([Confidence interval for correlation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144458/confidence-interval-for-correlation), for example.)  r’s command `cor.test` does give upper and lower bounds that are unequal distances from the statistic estimate.  The documentation describes that `cor.test` uses Fisher’s z transformation.

I need uncertainty for a weighted correlation - hundreds of them, actually.  The only weighted correlation command in r I have found so far that provides any uncertainty is `wtd.cor`.  It reports a single standard error for the correlation.  In the documentation I do not find a description of how the standard error is derived.

1. Is there an r command I’m overlooking or some other simple solution?

   If not, is there a better option than to write code to create bootstrapped confidence intervals?  For example, is there some reasonable (and check-able) guess about how the standard error was derived so that I could back-transform it using Fisher’s z?

I'm not sure whether this question belongs in statsExchange or stackOverflow - seems which one fits best could depend on the answer.